# How to invert the result of a diff?

Tags: bash, diff

I'm trying to create a logging script

Right now I need a way to get the different lines
I'm thinking of storing a copy of the sent log, and sending the difference

Example:

fullLog.txt

```
logged 1
logged 2
logged 3
```

cachedLog.txt

```
logged 1
```

And I want to get

```
logged 2
logged 3
```

as a variable
and then `cp fullLog.txt cachedLog.txt`

The issue is, `diff fullLog.txt cachedLog.txt | sed 's/^[<>] //g'` only prints

```
logged 1
```

How can I "invert" the result to get what I wanted?

Comment: It sounds like `diff` is the wrong tool for your job entirely. `comm` is probably a better fit.

Comment: ...`diff` exists to _calculate an edit that can be applied to one file to turn it into another_, doing a bunch of work (and thus, using algorithms which are, particularly in worst-case performance given pathological inputs, slower and more-memory-intensive than would otherwise be required) to make that file as short as possible. If you just want to know which lines are in both of two files, or in file A but not file B, that's exactly what `comm` is built for.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #36](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036).

Comment: OTOH, if you're dealing with transmitting log files specifically, something that's aware of timestamps and can compare them might be more appropriate. That would be an easy and appropriate task for `awk` (specifically GNU awk if your logs' timestamps aren't in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` or another ASCII-sort-friendly format and you need the timestamps parsed).

Comment: ...after all, for a log file you ideally just need to figure out the starting and ending timestamps and don't need to compare the content in the middle at all. That's _much_ faster once the files get large.

Comment: I want to know which lines are *not* in cachedLog @CharlesDuffy
Also I do not have timestamps

Comment: Yes, finding lines in file-A and _not_ in file-B is a thing `comm` is good at (and generally much more appropriate than `diff`).

Comment: In that case, it would be `comm -13 <(sort <cachedLog.txt) <(sort <fullLog.txt)`

Answer (score 1):

Solved: `comm -3 fullLog.txt cachedLog.txt`

Comment: Note that `comm` requires inputs to be sorted (a requirement that allows it to operate with constant memory requirements no matter how large the input files are, that being one of its advantages over `diff`).